# How to get job variables injected into the docker execution?

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I wonder if this is already part of the system...
I need to use the current gitlab user id and email (**$GITLAB_USER_ID**, **$GITLAB_USER_EMAIL**) injected into the execution of the docker image (to later configure the git repository).

Is there a magic way to do this ? or should I explicitly write the export commands into my **.gitlab-ci.yml** file (as a before_script for example) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried?  I'm almost positive those already are. Write a job that just calls `env` and see what variables are there.

Comment: I just try the **env** command, and I got my response there. thanks @JonathonReinhart for the tip.

Comment: I'm not sure why you didn't just try using the variables before bothering to ask the question on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Of course I did try, may be I did not spell correctly the env variable in my try. Sorry if you think I am a liar :(.

Answer (score 1):

I got my response by trying the `env` command on a build.
So yes every job variables are available into the docker execution env.